# fallocate -l 8E haystack.bin

Tags: ctf

I'm facing a ctf and I'm facing an 8exabytes big problem. The flag is inside a bin file which is inside a gz file.
The creation took place in these steps:
§Mounted my 10 exabyte flash drive
§fallocate -l 8E haystack.bin
§dd if=flag.txt bs=1 seek=[REDACTED] conv=notrunc of=haystack.bin
§gzip haystack.bin.
The file is located at a given URL.
Now, assuming that downloading the file is unthinkable, how do I recover the flag? I've tried everything but been in the dark for 12 hours. If someone kind with the desire and patience wants to accompany me towards the solution, I would be grateful. It's not for the score, we're not competitive in the least, it's just for the thirst for knowledge about a problem that completely displaces us. Thanks very much in advance for any help!

Curl with various flags trying to download certain chunks, hexdump, burp suite, dd, python scripts. Nothing gave me a result.